# Why for an inductor part is the RMS current rating is specified at 20°C rise and 40°C rise?

Tags: inductor

The inductor part from coilcraft (https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/597/xal4000-270751.pdf), RMS current rating  is specified for 20°C rise and 40°C rise. Is there any specific reason? In note 6 it is mentioned as the current rising from 25°C (ambient temp).

Also is only 25°C meant ambient temperature or any temperature between 20°C and 40°C meant to be ambient temp range?

so while designing which one they consider whether current rating of 20°C rise or 40°C rise temp?

Comment: Use `&deg;` for HTML degrees symbol. It works in the posts but not in the comments. Don't forget to add 'C' or 'F' to each measurement to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ambient is : –40°C to +125°C. Which becomes max. +165°C with 40°C rise.

Comment: Although it's true that a 40°C rise at 125°C gives 165°C, note that for example with the XAL4020-401 at 25°C a **14** Arms gives 40°C rise, but at 125°C almost **12** Arms gives 40°C! You have to derate like footnote 6 says (follow the link).

Answer (score 2):

At those ratings the component's temperature rises 20°C resp. 40°C with respect to the ambient temperature. So, at an ambient temperature of 35°C  the inductor's temperature becomes **about** 55°C resp. 75°C.

Footnote 6 says these values are tested/measured at an ambient temperature 25°C. So, at other ambient temperatures, the temperature rise is an indication / reference value.

NB. Ambient temperature  means the inductor's ambient temperature . So, if it is outside 35°C but your electronics is in a black box in the full sun, the ambient temperature for the inductor might be 75°C.

**Additional andwer to additional question**
Normally, you don't consider or pick a temperature rise and try stay within the rated current. It is the other way around: You calculate your rms current and calculate the rise in temperature (or use the derating link in the datasheet) and make sure to stay within the thermal limits.

Answer (score 1):

The inductor has DC (and ac, which depends upon frequency) resistance (7.55mΩ \$R_{DC}\$ for the 0.40µH inductor).  This resistance will cause the temperature of the inductor to rise as current flows through it.

As a guideline, they measured the temperature rise at an ambient temperature of 25°C and found for the 0.40µH inductor that 10A produced a 20°C rise or 45°C and 14A produced a 40°C rise or 65°C.

Now, figure an ambient temperature of –40°C to +125°C with a 40°C rise gives a maximum part temperature of +165°C.

If the part exceeds this maximum (+165°C), the coating on the wire will go through irreversible chemical changes (melt, burn) and the inductance will change.

As they ([Shielded Power Inductors](https://www.coilcraft.com/pdfs/xal4000.pdf)) say:

> This information is for reference only and does not represent absolute maximum ratings.
>
> Temperature rise is highly dependent on many factors including pcb land pattern, trace size, and proximity to other components. Therefore temperature rise should be verified in application conditions.

So this is general information to help you determine the maximum temperature the inductor will face, based on ambient temperature, current, etc.

They link a [calculator](https://www.coilcraft.com/apps/power_tools/compare/) to derate the inductance based upon frequency, current, ripple.  It shows:

- L vs I graphs
- Core & Winding Losses
- Temperature Rise
- Temperature Derating